# Converting 3D coordinates to 2D in 3ds max

Tags: c++, 3dsmax

I am trying to convert 3D coordinates of a point in plane object to 2D coordinates considering viewport width and height. 
I am writing the code in c++.

While going through 3Ds max documentation I found function "MapViewToScreen",
Will this function be enough? If so how to implement it. 
If there are any other methods too please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the link [map-world-point-to-viewport-coordinates](http://snipplr.com/view/11908/map-world-point-to-viewport-coordinates/)

Basically what you need to do is

```
//get Transfromation matrix of the plane
Matrix3 tmMatrix = inode->GetObjectTM( GetCOREInterface()->GetTime() );

ViewExp& vpt = GetCOREInterface()->GetActiveViewExp();
GraphicsWindow *gwindow= vpt.getGW();
gwindow->setTransform( Matrix3(1) );

//Your required point, consider only the X and Y part
IPoint3 out; // X and Y from the bottom left corner
Point3 in( your_3d_point * tmMatrix );
gwindow->hTransPoint(&in, &out);
```